# Difficulties obtaining math (italic) style in mhchem aligned equations with unicode-math

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, mhchem

This looks like a `unicode-math` bug to me, but perhaps an expert here can confirm this.

I am presently using the Libertinus math font family with luatex for my PhD thesis. For chemical equations, I am using the `mhchem` package.

The problem is that inside `align` environments, I cannot obtain any characters in math-mode, i.e. italics (even after explicitly coaxing it by surrounding desired characters with $ ... $). Here is a minimum example.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=10pt, convert={size=640x}]{standalone}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf]{mhchem}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math} % doesn't matter. All unicode math font behaves the same way
%\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf} % doesn't matter. All unicode math font behaves the same way

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\ce{A_x <=> B + y C} \\
\end{center}

\begin{align}
    \ce{A_x &<=> B + y C} \\
    \ce{X + Y &-> Z}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \ce{A_$x$ &<=> B + $y$ C} \\
    \ce{X + Y &-> Z}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

In the first equation, I obtain the correct behaviour, i.e. both `x` and `y` are correctly italicised.  But in the next two equations, I cannot get this desired behaviour. Especially in the third equation, even after surrounding `x` and `y` with $..$, it still typesets them upright as shown below

[image: wrong_typesetting]

If I comment the lines the lines pertaining to use of unicode math, as shown below

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=10pt, convert={size=640x}]{standalone}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf]{mhchem}
% \usepackage{unicode-math}
% \setmathfont{Libertinus Math}  % doesn't matter. All unicode fonts have this issue
% \setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf} % doesn't matter. All unicode fonts have this issue
```

and retain the rest of the source code, a luatex run gives me the correct output for all 3 cases, as shown below

[image: correct typesetting without libertinus]

whereupon `x` and `y` are typeset correctly in italic. Can I confirm that this is a `unicode-math` bug?

Comment: I can reproduce the behaviour. Let me add that you get the undesired output with Roman x and y as soon as you switch to math mode (also with `$...$` or `equation`).

Comment: @moewe Thank you for confirming. The Libertinus-math developer Khaled Hosny thinks that it is an issue with ```unicode-math``` . I am wondering if I should file a bug in their github repo.

Comment: You should definitely try and file a bug report about this. The difficult bit is where you should file the bug report. As the problem can be reproduced with other Unicode math fonts, it is not the Libertinus you should complain to. The choice is between `unicode-math` and `mhchem`. My hunch is that the `mhchem` developer should be the first to contact. But I see all important people know about this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it does not answer the original question of why this issue shows up with `unicode-math` and `mhchem` combo, my answer here using the alternative `chemformula` package should provide a viable workaround for anyone facing this (or a similar) issue.

```
%! TEX-program = lualatex
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=10pt, convert={size=640x}]{standalone}
% \usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Numbers={Proportional},Ligatures={TeX, Common%, Historic, Contextual, Rare, Discretionary
}]{Libertinus Serif}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{Libertinus Mono}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \ch{A_{$x$} <=> B + $y$ C} \\
\end{center}

\begin{align}
    \ch{A_{$x$} &<=> B + $y$ C} \\
    \ch{X + Y &-> Z}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Note that `mhchem` has been commented out and instead we use `chemformula`. Note also the additional grouping required for the subscripted math-mode `x` when using `chemformula`.

Anyway, we obtain the desired output as shown here:

[image: output_using_chemformula]

Perhaps a reasonable alternative would be to use `chemformula` until this issue is fixed.  (It is unclear by who: `unicode-math` team or `mhchem` developer?).

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed with mhchem v4.08 (2018-06-22).

Comment: Thank you. Does align also work?

Comment: It should. (align wasn't the cause, but math mode.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in math mhchem surrounds everything with `\mathrm`. And this change the  `\Umathcode`. You could try to add as a hook \symit. But it doesn't work if the argument doesn't consist of a single char (mhchem actively sets in this case the argument in roman also without unicode-math).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf]{mhchem}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$\ce{A_{\symit{x}}}$

\makeatletter
\def\mhchem@hook@beforeItalicMath{\symit}

$ \ce{A_x} \ce{A_{xxxx}} $

 %not a solution but only to demonstrate that removing the \mathrm avoids the problem:
\def\mhchem@option@mathFont{}%{\mathrm}

${\ce{A_x}}$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. If it doesn't suffer from this issue, maybe I can use ```chemformula``` instead of ```mhchem``` ? I need to proceed with my PhD thesis anyway.  The removal of ```\mathrm``` is not a solution for me since it makes everything italic.

Comment: I can't tell you if you should switch. Be aware that explicit markup (`$\ce{A_{\symit{xxxx}}}$`)  will work.

Comment: Hmm, reading this from page 3 of the official ```chemformula``` [manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemformula/chemformula_en.pdf) gives me some hope: "Another notable dierence: chemformula tries to avoid math mode whenever possible"

Comment: But you wan't math mode for the subscript. So don't let go hope to high and run some tests first.

Comment: Yes. It works!! As per page 22 of the official chemformula [manual](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemformula/chemformula_en.pdf): "If you especially want to input math you just enclose it with $ $". I tried it and it works. I shall post the code with chemformula  as an answer (suggesting it as a possible workaround to others facing similar issues).