# Italic math within \mathrm

Tags: math-mode, fonts, unicode-math

How can I escape to "normal math" from within `\mathrm`?

In my package mhchem, I used `\text{\ensuremath{2n-1}}` which did a perfect job. However, `unicode-math` came along, broke established behavior and I now need to find another way ([[1]](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/459), [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428686/73371)).

`\mathnormal` was suggested, but that renders digits differently.

So, what is an alternative for this code that works in a generic setup?

`\mathrm{...\text{\ensuremath{2n-1}}...}`

Comment: your question is phrased as a general question but really you are asking about a unicode-math specific context and the answer is to use a unicode-math specific command to undo its changes, as discussed in github.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, I don't want a `unicode-math`-specific solution. I want a generic one and avoid any "Is `unicode-math` active?" code in my package.

Comment: then sorry you are doomed.  The question has no general answer for any possible definition of `\mathrm`

Comment: unicode tex engines like xetex and luatex have two essentially separate math layout engines. One for classic tex tfm fonts and one for opentype fonts with a MATH table. unicode-math package tries as far as possible to make the surface syntax for the user  the same, but internally _everything_ is different and if you are using "hidden" math contexts then it is not likely that you can avoid having conditional code for the two contexts

Comment: Can you please show an example for the changed digits?

Comment: example for changed digits: [LaTeX code](https://pastebin.com/ZH85s5Fc) and [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjfpq.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "escaping to normal math from within `\mathrm`, but I think (hope?) that `\mathrm{\symit{2n-1}}` does what you need.

Here's a table to show the output of the 4 available `\sym<xx>` directives.
After that, a contrast between `\mathrm{\text{\ensuremath{2n-1}}}` and `\mathrm{\symit{2n-1}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text and \ensuremath macros
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{@{} >{$}l<{$} >{$\ttfamily}l<{$} l}
default    &               & 2n-1 \\
upright    & \string\symup & \symup{2n-1} \\
bold       & \string\symbf & \symbf{2n-1} \\
italic     & \string\symit & \symit{2n-1} \\
sans-serif & \string\symsf & \symsf{2n-1}
\end{array}$

\medskip
$\mathrm{2n-1}$ \& $\symup{2n-1}$

$\mathrm{\text{\ensuremath{2n-1}}}$ \& 
$\mathrm{\symit{2n-1}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, `\mathrm{\symit{2n-1}}` does what I need. Initially, I was looking for code that worked everywhere, but, according to David, that is not possible. So, I guess my package will need a "if unicode-math" condition.

Comment: @mhchem - You may want to load the `ifluatex` and `ifxetex` packages, and use them to set up high-level macros whose definitions will differ depending on whether LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or pdfLaTeX is in use.

Comment: I don't understand. I could compile a document with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and the command `\symit` would still be undefined (when the package `unicode-math` was not loaded).

Comment: @mhchem - Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I was assuming that if LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX are used to compile the document, the `unicode-math` package would be loaded.

Comment: Obervation: while `$2n-1$` and `$\symit{2n-1}$` liik identical, `$\Delta$` will differ from `$\symit{\Delta}$`